# Amazon ELB forwarding http request changes request.RemoteAddress

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-elb

We are using Amazon EC2 services to host our play application on live. I have a quite important problem with Elastic Load Balancer. In my application I need request remote address and I am using play framework controller's `request.remoteAddress` property for it. However on Amazon it is stored always as load balancers ip address which is misleading us as we cannot track request remote address.

Is there something like a setting in Amazon ELB Configuration for forwarded requests? In Apache i think there is a solution for that but I have skimmed through ELB documentation and could not find any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found an elegant solution that Play Framework have a support such as `XForwardedSupport`. I am planning to test it in a short while.

Details of XForwardedSupport is [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#XForwardedSupport)

Answer (score 3):

i think you can use this when you a behind an proxy or load balancer:

```
String ip = Http.Request.current().headers.get("x-forwarded-for")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is an alternative but I think using XForwardedSupport is much better as I don't need to change all my code just change config.